# Arrange age group in correct order

Tags: r

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("15-25", "0-4", "5-10", "11-14", "100+"))
```

How do I sort is to 0-4 comes first and 100+ last? 
Dplyr solution would be nice, arrange does not work for me.

Comment: i went through the links shared, to reorder the factor, we had to explicitly specify the levels in `factor()` right? another approach could be `mixedsort` from `gtools` package where it can sort directly. Just a thought. Do correct if I'm wrong. @Cath Sotos, Imo

Comment: something like `factor(df$x, levels = mixedsort(df$x)`

Comment: @Sotos mind sharing your views on my comments. Since here the levels are numeric though stored as strings, we can reorder them without explicitly writing them in `levels = `

Comment: was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Is there any smart way to do without typing in every single one? The above was just one exactly, I actually have 20 groups, where two of them is not in correct order. One is first, when it should be last and the other is around the middle, but should be number 2

Comment: my code didn't require to type every single. You might have to raise a new question or read through the links shared above